# Is there a way to define a class instance is None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, when I have such a `Node` class defined.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=None, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.val is not None
```

When I initialize it with empty arguments, like below. Is there a way to self-define method to say `a is None`?

```py
a = Node()
a is None # False, but can it be true if I want?
```

Comment: No, a class instance can't be `None`.

Comment: This would break lots of things, because you'd get errors when you try to call class methods.

Comment: You'd have to check for `None` before every method call.

Comment: The `__bool__` method will allow you to write `if a:` and `if not a:`

Comment: What in the class do you want to be none? A class on its own cannot be none. You have to check for a return of a method or an attribute for it to be classified. A class solely cannot be none.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish this way? Why not just *actually use None* in the places where you want `is None` to be true? What actually *is* a `Node`, and what are you planning to *do with* these Nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, but...

You cannot override the `is`, `and`, or `or` operators.

Defining `__bool__` allows you to write statements like

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.val is not None   # <--- added "return"

for val in (0, 1, True, None):
    n = Node(val)
    # These three are equivalent
    if n:
        assert n.__bool__()
        assert n.val is not None
    # These three are equivalent
    else:
        assert not n.__bool__()
        assert n.val is None
```

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**bool**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)

Comment: He did define `__bool__`.

Comment: True, clarified answer

Comment: @Barmar: Note the OP didn't define `__bool__()` to return anything.

Comment: Cireo: There's no variable named `x`. Also, don't use `n.__bool__()`, use `bool(n)`, or even more simply: `assert n`.

Comment: I'm not suggesting he (or anyone) writes code using `__bool__()`, that is for pedagogical purposes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I truely had a bug earlier. So I now understand that is None is something that cannot be modified.

Answer (score 5):

While you cannot override the `is` comparison, you can at least override the equality operator if you want to quickly check up whether a specific parameter (or condition) within your class should yield `True` on comparison, e.g.:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=None, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        return obj == self.val

n = Node()
print(n == None)  # True
n = Node(5)
print(n == None)  # False
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for sharing about this __eq__ method. works as well as __bool__ method.

Answer (score 2):

This may not do exactly what you want but you could overwrite the `__new__` class method so that, when the class constructor is called with no arguments, the `None` object is returned instead of an instance of `Node`.

I think this should work (my metaclass knowledge is spotty).

```
class Node:
    def __new__(cls, val=None, next=None):
        if val is None and next is None:
            return None

        return super().__init__(cls, val, next)

    def __init__(self, val, next):
        if self is None:
            return

        ...
```

It is my duty to recommend that you not go down this route, however.  Fiddling with `__new__` is tricky and dangerous and is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Oh, really?  Thanks.  Told you my metaclass knowledge was spotty.

Comment: There is no metaclass here... `__new__` is actually just a constructor, (`__init__` is technically an initializer). A metaclass is the *class of a class*. All classes are merely instances of `type`. You can inherit from `type` to create a metaclass, but that isn't what you need here. What you've shown here *is* correct, although, as you already say, probably not the best route. I think the OP probably just needs something else. Once your constructor starts returning objects not of the same type you've created a problem, IMO...

Comment: @juanpa: IMO it's fine to use @classmethod on `__new__()` even if it's not necessary — "Explicit is better than implicit" in Python.

Comment: Daniel: One potential problem: `isinstance(Node(), Node)` → `False`.

Comment: That's true.  It's not a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This blows me out. I'll forget about it.. and take it as "is None" is not modifiable.

Comment: @martineau I don't want to extend the rabbit hole too far, but you could define a metaclass (for real this time) and define `__instancecheck__` to say that `None` was an instance....  <here be dragons>

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the class variable as a parameter. Try below code lines.

```
class dummy(object):
     empty_array = []
     def __init__(self, size):
        self.empty_array = [[None]*2 for i in range(size)]

a = dummy(3)
print (a.empty_array)
```